# Observable throwing Exception When Updating MutableLiveData

Tags: java, android, android-livedata

I am having issues when trying to update my MutableLiveData. I am calling a login function from my ViewModel to update my UI. In my ViewModel, I make a call to my API server, but when I call .notify(), I get a crash:

> java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before notify()

Where should I put this so it works

Here is my XML file

```
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.kidzmedia.radio.activities.login.LoginViewModel" />
    </data>

....

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
        android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.doLogin()}"
        android:text="Login" />
```

My ViewModel

```
public class LoginViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<User> userMutableLiveData;

....

    public void doLogin() {
        userMutableLiveData = userApi.loginUser(email, password);
        Log.i("LOGIN", "do Login");

        //userMutableLiveData.setValue(tmpUser.getValue());
    }

    LiveData<User> getUser() {
        if (userMutableLiveData == null) {
            userMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        }

        return userMutableLiveData;
    }
```

my UI

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActivityLoginBinding activityLoginBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_login);
        //activityLoginBinding.setViewModel(ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(LoginViewModel.class);

        LoginViewModel loginViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(LoginViewModel.class);
        activityLoginBinding.setViewModel(loginViewModel);

        loginViewModel.getUser().observe(this, new Observer<User>() {

            @Override
            public void onChanged(User user) {
                if (user != null)
                    // DO STUFF
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My Api Server:

```
public class UserApi {

    private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    public MutableLiveData<User> loginUser(String email, String password) {


        User loginUser = new User(email, password);

        final MutableLiveData<User> mutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

        UserService userApi = APIUtils.getUserService();
        userApi.doLoginUser(loginUser).enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                mutableLiveData.setValue(response.body());

                // THIS IS WHERE IT CRASHES
                mutableLiveData.notify();
            }
        });

        return mutableLiveData;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need to call `notify()`? That's a very low level java API for synchronization, which you should never need to use in an Android app, given the way LiveData works.

Comment: If you look at my function "public void doLogin()" in LoginViewModel, you'll see some code I commented out, this didn't work. The UI gets a null for User (and thanks for your help)

Comment: That doesn't really help me understand why you need to call `notify()`.  That method can only be called within a synchronized block, which you don't have here, and is not necessary at all.  I suggest doing a web search for that error message to learn more.

Comment: Ok, if I remove the ".notify()", then how can I get the MutableLiveData to update?

Comment: It does so automatically - that's the way LiveData works.  All observers will see the updated value.  You might want to rephrase your question in terms of what specifically isn't working the way you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for your comment

> if I remove the ".notify()", then how can I get the MutableLiveData to update?

I know only 2 ways. May be it help you.

1. You can send callback function to `loginUser()` in arguments.
2. You can use `execute` instead `enqueue` and work with request synchronously. But you'll need to do this in another thread.

Comment: Awesome, I was banging my head over this all weekend, it solved my problems. Thanks!